# Интерфейс дико глючит - проблема с ImageView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-imageview

Использую `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager` - 2 плитки в ряд. В качестве корневого элемента айтема использую собственный класс `RRL`

```
public class RRL extends RelativeLayout
{
public RRL(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public RRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

Для того, чтобы получились квадраты. Вот разметка айтема

```
<f.f.f.RRL
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/chapter_iv"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#77000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/chapter_footer"/>

</LinearLayout>

</f.f.f.RRL>
```

`RecyclerView` находится в `LinearLayout`. В свою очередь он является верхним ребёнком `ViewFlipper`. Навигация бокового меню реализована методом `setDisplayedChild`. Всего 4 экрана, поэтому я не стал использовать какие-то сложные элементы.

На главном экране с сеткой глючит боковое меню при его открытии/закрытии. Если перейти на любой другой экран, то все отлично. Если опять вернуться к первому, то боковое меню так же тупит. Что делать?

В сетке я вывожу только 2 айтема с одной и той же картинкой (весит 58Кб). Проблема не ясна, ранее не сталкивался. Обьяснить её гуглу затрудняюсь

**Главная разметка**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:background="#512da8"/>

        <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/screen_flipper">

        <include layout="@layout/home_content"/>
        <include layout="@layout/quest_content"/>
        <include layout="@layout/quest_content"/>
        <include layout="@layout/quest_content"/>

        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Как именно глючит? Можно пожалуйста по подробнее? К тому же у вас слишком много вложенных лэйаутов плюс ко всему по гайдлайнам не советуют вкладывать один скролющийся лэйаут в другой.

Comment: Если от кромки экрана выдвинуть панель, то она дергаясь, по делениями вылезает. Тоже самое с закрытием

Comment: Если нажать на гамбургег, то на время все зависает и через некоторое время панель без анимации открывается.

Comment: У меня только один прокручиваемый элемент - сама сетка. `ViewFlipper`, а не `ViewPager`

Comment: Может в вопросе не хватает главной разметки?

Comment: Это очень плохая идея добавлять`ViewFlipper` в `DrawerLayout`. Постарайтесь избежать этого.

Comment: Я не знаю что делать... :( На каждой активности нельзя боковое меню использовать. Фрагменты я не буду юзать, это полная фигня, весь код карявый какой-то становится

Comment: `ViewPager` нуждается в фрагментах.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, ViewPager может и без фрагментов. В него можно просто обычную разметку поместить